# Passing null to an oracle stored proc from python on a user defined type

Tags: python, stored-procedures, cx-oracle

I am trying to use an Oracle stored proc from python and have trouble with user defined types.

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the issue

```
create or replace
TYPE  test_type AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

create or replace procedure python_test (
 a in number,
 b in test_type) as
begin
  null;
end;
/
```

I actually am not looking to pass anything as test_type from python but simply not set it to anything (which is allowed by real life stored proc).

In SQL, the following works:

```
execute python_test(1,null);
```

However, from python with cx_Oracle, the following command

```
cursor.callproc('python_test', [1, None])
```

gives me the following error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PYTHON_TEST'

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need to use cursor.setinputsizes() in order to make this work as expected. If you simply use the default processing None is treated as a string, which isn't what is expected here. Instead, do something like the following:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.Connection("cx_Oracle/welcome@oracle-laptop/T122")
cursor = conn.cursor()

var = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT, typename = "TEST_TYPE")
cursor.setinputsizes(None, var)
cursor.callproc("python_test", [1, None])
```

Comment: Sorry for following up on this so late. it does note seem to work:
cur.setinputsizes(None, [str, 0])
cur.callproc('python_test', [1, None])

I get the same PLS-00306 error

Comment: Yeah, I thought you were referring to a PL/SQL array instead of a SQL collection object. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It still doesn't work unfortunately for me (same error). The error message is really not helpful: is there a way to get more verbose output about what's going wrong? Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: That error message comes from Oracle so there isn't much more that can be done there. I've updated my answer to show the complete code. You can simply replace the credentials with your own and run it and it should work. I'm using the latest version (6.2).

Comment: Apologies for getting back on this so late: this works like a charm!